# PHP Error in number_format

Tags: php, number-formatting

i have this variable: `$this->{$prefix . '_total'}` that can equal any number depending on the case but for the time being lets say `$this->{$prefix . '_total'} = 4000`.

So i use `$this->{$prefix . '_total'}` in order to get `4,000`.

However, i dont know why but i get `4` instead.

Whats happening to the other zeros?? I tried with different values such as `1564.13` for example and in all cases the output its only the very first number. So i tried it like this:

```
number_format(($this->{$prefix . '_total'}*100000))
```

and it doesnt work either! I still get only the first digit. Why?? This blows my mind at so many levels. Please help.

Thank you.

Full function:

```
function render($indent = "", InvoicePayment $payment = null)
{
$prefix = (!is_null($payment) && !$payment->isFirst()) ? 'second' : 'first';
$tm_added = is_null($payment) ? $this->tm_added : $payment->dattm;

$newline = "\r\n";

$price_width = max(mb_strlen(Am_Currency::render($this->{$prefix . '_total'}, $this->currency)), 8);

$column_padding = 1;
$column_title_max = 60;
$column_title_min = 20;
$column_qty = 4 + $price_width;
$column_num = 3;
$column_amount = $price_width;
$space = str_repeat(' ', $column_padding);

$max_length = 0;
foreach ($this->getItems() as $item) {
    $max_length = max(mb_strlen(___($item->item_title)), $max_length);
}

$column_title = max(min($max_length, $column_title_max), $column_title_min);
$row_width = $column_num + $column_padding +
             $column_title + $column_padding +
             $column_qty + $column_padding +
             $column_amount + $column_padding;

$column_total = $column_title +
                $column_qty + $column_padding;
$total_space = str_repeat(' ', $column_padding + $column_num + $column_padding);

$border = $indent . str_repeat('-', $row_width) . "$newline";

$out = $indent . ___("Invoice") . ' #' . $this->public_id . " / " . amDate($tm_added) . "$newline";
$out .= $border;
$num = 1;
foreach ($this->getItems() as $item) {
    $title = explode("\n", $this->wordWrap(___($item->item_title), $column_title, "\n", true));
    $out .= $indent . sprintf("{$space}%{$column_num}s{$space}%-{$column_title}s{$space}%{$column_qty}s{$space}%{$price_width}s$newline",
        $num . '.', $title[0], $item->qty . 'x' . Am_Currency::render($item->{$prefix . '_price'}, $this->currency), Am_Currency::render($item->{$prefix . '_total'}, $this->currency));
    for ($i=1; $i<count($title); $i++)
        $out .= $indent . sprintf("{$space}%{$column_num}s{$space}%-{$column_title}s$newline", ' ', $title[$i]);
    $num++;
}
$out .= $border;
if ($this->{$prefix . '_subtotal'} != $this->{$prefix . '_total'})
    $out .= $indent . sprintf("{$total_space}%-{$column_total}s{$space}%{$price_width}s$newline", ___('Subtotal'), Am_Currency::render($this->{$prefix . '_subtotal'}, $this->currency));
if ($this->{$prefix . '_discount'} > 0)
    $out .= $indent . sprintf("{$total_space}%-{$column_total}s{$space}%{$price_width}s$newline", ___('Discount'), Am_Currency::render($this->{$prefix . '_discount'}, $this->currency));
if ($this->{$prefix . '_shipping'} > 0)
    $out .= $indent . sprintf("{$total_space}%-{$column_total}s{$space}%{$price_width}s$newline", ___('Shipping'), Am_Currency::render($this->{$prefix . '_shipping'}, $this->currency));
if ($this->{$prefix . '_tax'} > 0)
    $out .= $indent . sprintf("{$total_space}%-{$column_total}s{$space}%{$price_width}s$newline", ___('Tax'), Am_Currency::render(number_format($this->{$prefix . '_tax'}), $this->currency));
$out .= $indent . sprintf("{$total_space}%-{$column_total}s{$space}%{$price_width}s$newline", ___('Total'), Am_Currency::render($this->{$prefix . '_total'}, $this->currency));
$out .= $border;
if ($this->rebill_times) {
    $terms = explode("\n", $this->wordWrap(___($this->getTerms()), $row_width, "\n", true));
    foreach ($terms as $term_part)
        $out .= $indent . $term_part . $newline;
    $out .= $border;
}
return $out;
}
```

And this is the render function

```
static function render($value, $currency = null, $locale = null)
    {
        return (string)self::create($value, $currency, $locale);
    } 



 public function __toString()
    {
        $format = array_key_exists($this->currency, $this->formats) ? 
            $this->formats[$this->currency] :
            '%.2f %s';
        return sprintf($format, $this->value, $this->currency);
    }
```

Comment: Are you just displaying the output with `echo`?

Comment: Not exactly, its inside a function. But if i do it like this number_format("4000000000000000.00") then i get 40

Comment: Running php on a file containing `<?php echo number_format("4000000000000000.00") ?>` prints 4,000,000,000,000,000 for me. Are you sure the string isn't being processed by something else before being output?

Comment: Please post a complete working example to http://3v4l.org or similar, this is not really "possible" as you describe it.

Comment: I guess so, but the function is very complicated to post it here. The thing is that if i write it like this: number_format($number) i will only get 4 where im supposed to get 4000, but if i write it like this: number_format("4000000000000000.00") then i get 40. Weird, isnt?

Comment: Difficult to post it to 3v4l.org or any since the code is only part of a bigger one that is also part of a full script that comprises several files.

Comment: Post a *minimal* example that demonstrates the problem. Let's put it this way: `number_format` works fine for millions of people worldwide, only you have a problem with it **as part of a larger piece of code**. Occam's razor suggests that the problem is **in the rest of your code**, not in `number_format`.

Comment: Okay, i added the full function to my first post, thats all i can do.

Comment: And what does `Am_Currency::render` do?

Comment: It renders the quantity, in this case 4000 and adds the currency either at the beginning or the end of the amount.

Comment: Is it likely that `Am_Currency::render` casts the number to an `int`, which discards parts of the formatted string...?!

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<?php
   echo number_format($number,0,'',',');
?>
```

Comment: Its too long to post here as its part of a full script that comprises several files.

Answer (score -1):

Stabbing into the dark here to explain the phenomenon:

```
echo (int)number_format(1000);
```

This results in "1". Because `number_format` produces "1,000", and `(int)` tries to parse it back into an integer, and since "`,`" is not a valid part of an integer specification that's where it stops and returns only "`1`". See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion.

Something like this must be happening in your `Am_Currency::render`.

Comment: Hi, i added the function to my code. Seems like thats the responsible for all this.